# How do I duplicate a photo before editing it on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, photos, photos.app

How do I duplicate a photo before editing it on my iPad? When I first bought my Apple laptop years ago, there was a simple way to simply choose ‘duplicate picture’ and so you can go in and edit it while you keep the original intact. That functionality seems to have disappeared! Evolution or devolution?

Answer (score 1):

In **Photos**, tap the photo to select it, then tap the **Action** *button* (square with an upwards arrow) and then scroll down to the **Duplicate** *command*.